# Medicines as good as surgery or devices for which heart conditions?

Tags: heart-disease

For most heart disease, there are three kinds of treatments available:

- medicines
- devices (percutaneous interventions - usually performed via arteries and veins of upper thigh) and
- surgery e.g. coronary artery bypass grafting (CABG) and closure/correciton of cardiac defects.

Patients who get devices or undergo surgery usually have to continue taking medicines as well.

For which common heart conditions just medicines are as good as more invasive treatments i.e. devices and surgery? Some studies have shown that patients with mild angina do as well on medicines as after interventions or surgery. Your comments on this and other similar heart diseases will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find examples of patients with mild angina actually having surgery? With mild angina, it would be most likely to not have surgery at all.

Comment: what about EECP (Enhanced External Counterpulsation) therapy ?